# Using composer php to avoid the dependency

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoloader

I got stuck in implementation of composer. I don't understand the autoload formation. I am going to sketch the file directory then you people just tell me how I formed the destination of a class into autoload:

```
|---------src/
|         |-----bitm/
|         |       |---person/
                         |person.php
|         |       |---Age/
                       |age.php
|         |-----vendor/
                  |----composer
                  |autoload.php
|         |

|         |composer.json

|         |  

|         |index.php
```

above structure is my folder structure in web server.

following code is for composer.json

```
{
"autoload":{
    "psr-4":{
        "bitm\\person" : "src"
    }
}}
```

following code is for index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Greeting</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
/*function __autoload($className){
    //var_dump($className);
   include_once($className.".php");
}*/
include_once("vendor/autoload.php");

use bitm\person\person;
use bitm\age\age;

$mamun=new person('Mamun');
$age=new age(24);

$mamun->greeting();
$age->personAge();


?>

</body>
</html>
```

I used namespace for person.php is bitm\person
and I used namespace for age.php is bitm\age.

my question is to you guys why it shows

> Fatal error: Class 'bitm\person\person' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\basis_mamun_ewu\Mamun\src\index.php on line 18

Comment: Can you post the top of `bitm/person/person.php`?

Comment: Take a look at https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading and http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: By careffully reading these small paragraphs and trying to apply them in your project, you'll solve these problems ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your ASCII-art correctly, you have four errors:

1. The `composer.json` is located inside the `src` directory. That's OK, but any paths related to autoloading are relative to the position of the `composer.json` file, and you have `src` in your autoloading path - wrong. The code you want to load is in the `bitm` directory.
2. The PSR-4 prefix has to end with a backslash. Composer might already have complained about this. Run `composer validate` to see this and probably more errors. As you already did with the inner backslash, it has to be escaped in JSON, so it should read `"bitm\\person\\"`.
3. The PSR-4 standard tells you that the prefix part is removed from the classname, and the remainder is converted into a path. If you have a class `bitm\person\person` and a prefix `bitm\person`, then the remainder of that classname is `person`, will be converted into the path `person.php` and assumed in the directory you gave in the `composer.json` file. I already mentioned that `src` was wrong, but as an example: Composer would try to load the file `src/person.php` (relative to the position of `composer.json`).
4. Although PHP classes are not case sensitive, PHP will not convert the class names cases when autoloading, and the class name will be transformed into a file name. But file systems are case sensitive (unless you are using Windows). You have a directory `Age`, but are using the namespace `age`. This will not match. Always use the same case everywhere.

Also note that you made a prefix for `bitm\person`, but not for `bitm\age`, so you cannot autoload the age classes. You can have multiple prefixes in the autoloading section, or use a more general `bitm` prefix that will catch all classes.

Comment: thnx bro! I was confused little bit about composer.your assistance really appreciated :)